# CSS - :hover state on mobile devices not triggered by :focus

Tags: html, css

I am creating a CSS plugin but have recently ran into a few issues getting the :hover state to trigger when on mobile. I have read that `:focus` should offer similar behaviour as well as another couple of tricks such as setting `cursor: pointer` however none of this has helped with my scenario so far. I would like to avoid Javascript/jQuery as far as possible as I wanted this to be a pure CSS solution.

This is what I have so far:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child bg-one">
        <a href="#">Los Angeles</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
    .parent {
    width: 45%;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.child {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    -moz-transition: all .5s;
    -o-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

/* Several different images */
.bg-one {background-image: url(https://media.timeout.com/images/101602611/image.jpg);}


a {
    display: none;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 50px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*text-decoration: none;*/
}

.parent:hover .child, .parent:focus .child {
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

.parent:hover .child:before, .parent:focus .child:before {
    display: block;
}

.parent:hover a, .parent:focus a {
    display: block;
}

.child:before {
    content: "";
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(52,73,94,0.75);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r67gxp61/

Comment: good one, hover on mobile :))

Comment: @madalinivascu Yes - annoying :P but from what i could research, :focus should have worked

Answer (score 0):

Use tabindex for the focus, there is no hover in mobile

```
<div class="parent" tabindex="0">
    <div class="child bg-one">
        <a href="#">Los Angeles</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7qjkofnf/

Comment: there is no hover state on mobile,you better convert you hover into a click or remove it

Comment: Is there any way of doing this without JS?

Comment: you can't do it,even with js,have you ever seen a hover effect on a phone ?, how do you psychically create the hover?

Comment: I meant was there a way of doing a mobile click event without JS but I'ma assuming no.

Comment: wrap the element in a link